# What is causing arbitrary JTree Nodes to incorrectly display their names and how can I stop it from happening?

Tags: java, jtree

I have constructed a rather large JTree from XML data, literally thousands of nodes, most of which display correctly. However for some reason some node's `userData` Strings are not being fully displayed, rather thay are cut short or cut off completely with `...` appended to the end of the name.

[image]

The affected Nodes appear to be random, and are different each time the tree is refreshed or recreated from the XML.

### Things I've ruled out:

**Not enough space to display the full name.**

1. The JTree is inside a JScrollPane with plenty of horizontal space, the JScrollPane isn't even showing a horizontal scroll bar to indicate a lack of space.
2. Even the shortest name can be affected.
3. The cut off point isn't consistent for all shortened node names.

**Incomplete name loaded from XML**

1. If the affected node isn't a leaf and is then expanded or collapsed, the full name is displayed properly when it is re-rendered, the XML isn't consulted at all during this process.

### EDIT:

As requested some explanation of the code behind the JTree:

The creation of the TreeModel and the population of the tree:

```
public XMLDialogTree(Document doc)
    {
        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(buildTreeNode(doc.getElementsByTagName("Dialogs").item(0)));
        setModel(treeModel);
    }

// A recursive function to build the tree
private DefaultMutableTreeNode buildTreeNode(Node xmlNode)
    {
        // Make sure the node's name is a description of what it is, as opposed to a generic XML tag
        XMLDialogTreeNode = new XMLDialogTreeNode(xmlNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
        treeNode.controlName = xmlNode.getNodeName();

        // Add children to the treeNode based on the xmlNode's children
        NodeList nodeList = xmlNode.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node tempNode = nodeList.item(i);
                if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {
                        // loop again if has child nodes
                        treeNode.add(buildTreeNode(tempNode));
                    }
            }
        return treeNode;
    }
```

Where `doc` is an `org.w3c.dom.Document` containing parsed XML and an `XMLDialogTreeNode` is literally just a `javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode` extended to contain `String controlName = "CustomNodeName"`

The custom CellRenderer is as follows, The code is pretty much all to do with loading custom icons, nothing that should affect the Displayed name.

```
public class XMLDialogTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Icons used in the JTree, loaded once on an as needed basis once, and stored here.
    private static final Map<String, Icon> icons = new HashMap<String, Icon>();

    static
        {
            // Make sure the default icon is loaded
            loadIcon("_not_found");
        }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            XMLDialogTreeNode node = (XMLDialogTreeNode) value;

            setIcons(node.controlName);

            super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, exp, false/* leaf */, row, hasFocus);
            return this;
        }

    /**
     * Assigns both the open and close icons, which are specific to a certain control. Loads them if necessary.
     * 
     * @param controlName
     *            - The name of the control in the XML and the name of the image in the resources.treeIcons package.
     */
    private final void setIcons(String controlName)
        {
            // Make sure the Node has a controlName set
            if (controlName != null)
                {
                    // Try and get a pre-loaded icon
                    Icon controlIcon = icons.get(controlName);
                    // It wasn't there, try loading it
                    if (controlIcon == null)
                        loadIcon(controlName);

                    // If the icon doesn't exist, it is set to a default so this code is safe
                    setOpenIcon(controlIcon);
                    setClosedIcon(controlIcon);
                    // Stop here so we don't just set the default icons again
                    return;
                }
            setOpenIcon(getDefaultOpenIcon());
            setClosedIcon(getDefaultClosedIcon());
        }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @param iconName
     * @return
     */
    private static final void loadIcon(String iconName)
        {
            URL url = XMLDialogTreeCellRenderer.class.getResource("/com/phabrix/resources/dialogTreeIcons/" + iconName + ".png");
            if (url == null)
                {
                    // Tell the developer that they need to make a new icon for a new control type
                    if (Main.DEBUG && !iconName.equals("Dialogs"))
                        System.out.println("There is no icon for the control named: " + iconName);
                    url = XMLDialogTreeCellRenderer.class.getResource("/com/phabrix/resources/dialogTreeIcons/_not_found.png");
                }

            icons.put(iconName, new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url)));
        }
}
```

Comment: you need to edit your question showing relevant code snippets, where you instanciate objects, populate the model, any listeners

Comment: Is it always the same nodes that are affected? If so, maybe you can reproduce it in an [MCVE](stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE). It could be a combination of the name and the level of nesting.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Like I said in the question, the affected nodes are different every time.

Comment: @guido My code is very standard, the only non-java code I'm using is my extended DefaultTreeCellRenderer, and then the modifications only relate to the custom Icons

Comment: it may be the cell renderer, it may be the way you call `nodeChanged`, if you call `reload`, or else, difficult to tell without seeing at the least some code, or better the minimal program that reproduce the problem

Comment: Does the problem also occur when you use the DefaultTreeCellRenderer, instead of your derived class?

Comment: @S.L.Barth No, so the issue must be with my own CellRenderer, I'll look into it, I've posted the code

Comment: @S.L.Barth I found the issue. The affected Nodes in every case, were the first Node to be displayed in the tree with a specific Icon. While the icon was displaying properly (not sure how) my code wasn't setting the icon until the second Node with a particular Icon was rendered and this was somehow upsetting the rendering of the name, while still showing the icon (which wasn't loaded...)

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! Time for a self-answer I guess.

Comment: @S.L.Barth It is times like these, when I realise I've just been stupid, that I wish I could take down my own questions... Will this really ever help anyone else?

Comment: You should be able to delete this question, as it has no upvoted answers. But don't forget that it's always easy to know what went wrong with the wisdom of hindsight. 
I could imagine a future visitor with their own custom CellRenderer having the same or a very similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a simple answer; this code:

```
// Try and get a pre-loaded icon
Icon controlIcon = icons.get(controlName);
// It wasn't there, try loading it
if (controlIcon == null)
    loadIcon(controlName);
```

became this code:

```
// Try and get a pre-loaded icon
Icon controlIcon = icons.get(controlName);
// It wasn't there, try loading it
if (controlIcon == null)
{
    loadIcon(controlName);
    controlIcon = icons.get(controlName);
}
```

Note that upon checking to see if our Icon variable is null, and then making sure an Icon has been loaded into the program, I now actually make sure that the Icon variable is updated so it is no longer null.

The affected Nodes in my tree were not random or fluctuating as I previously thought. It was always the first node to be drawn with each of the icons (different depending on the order I opened up the tree). I am loading each icon once, then caching it (the tree is huge and re-loading the same icon many times was a big performance hit). Essentially the node was created with just text, then had an icon set after being shown, which shunted the text and caused the end to be cut off. As above, the solution was to not forget to set the icon after loading it for the first time. A better solution would be for my `icons.get()` to be wrapped in such a way as to guarantee an icon was returned and to encapsulate the cache optimisation.

Comment: I've waited a bit with upvoting this, in case you decide to delete the question after all. If you decide you want to delete it, @-comment me and I can retract my vote. Personally, I think the vote is well-deserved for managing to solve your own problem.

Comment: Thanks, after what you said I decided to leave it up as the behavior described above is bizarre and might be hard for other people to debug too.